# xaml - How to specify which ContentTemplateSelector to use?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol, contenttemplateselector

I've seen a ton of examples where a content control's `ContentTemplateSelector` property is assigned a `StaticResource`.

Example: `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>`

MSDN states:

> Typically, you create a DataTemplateSelector when you have more than
>   one DataTemplate for the same type of objects and you want to supply
>   your own logic to choose a DataTemplate to apply based on the
>   properties of each data object.

Source: [DataTemplateSelector Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8)

Knowing this - my situation is that I have **two types of objects** *where each object has its own set of data templates* it can use. Is there any way I can simply have the content control's `ContentTemplateSelector` *bind* to a `ContentTemplateSelector` property on the view model? The tricky part is that the data templates are defined in the xaml file - I can't just initialized a new instance of the specific `ContentTemplateSelector` for that class.

Additional info: I have a parent view model where each of its subclasses should be represented as a **different type of object**. So depending on which subclass view model is toggled, it should use its respective `ContentTemplateSelector` and data templates.

I've also gotten the above to work with a converter, but I want to stay away from this. Ideally, I'd like to have code that makes this process as general as possible. i.e. Not needing to maintain the converter code to add *new types of objects* in the future just to return the right `DataTemplateSelector`. The case should be that anytime a new subclass is added, it'll just work right away.

Comment: You never need more than one ContentTemplateSelector. It can provide different DataTemplates depending on the type *and* other criteria of a data item at the same time.

Comment: You could write a template selector that selects another template selector based on some configurable criteria, and then, internally, uses the selected selector to select a template. It could even be recursive. But you'd have to write it yourself.

Comment: *"I have a parent view model where each of its subclasses should be represented as a different type of object. So depending on which subclass view model is toggled..."* -- I wonder if you're using "subclass" and "type of object" in the same sense as I'd use those terms.

Comment: I can't remember the last time i saw a ContentTemplateSelector used in commercial code. Is a data template with datatype selection not going to work? It works with subtypes.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I meant the subclasses are different types of objects in the way that I would like to present them. i.e. 3 domains of life splits into Bacteria, Archaea, and Eukaryota (see link: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Phylogenetic_tree.svg/440px-Phylogenetic_tree.svg.png). We can say that those represent my subclasses and each of their subclasses will use a different data template. I don't want to maintain a file of 150 data templates if I can help it by splitting them up into smaller groups, especially if I expect that we could find "more domains" in the future.

Comment: @Andy I was initially using the DataType selection - didn't realize it works with subtypes. Will look into that too - thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could define a template for Bacteria which will be applied to all subtypes of that.

Comment: @Andy While it doesn't make much sense in this example, I was actually hoping to have a template for each of the subdomains that branches off from each of the main domains (as an equivalent to what I'm working with) - such that each domain will have its own DataTemplateSelector (i.e. BacteriaDataTemplateSelector, ArchaeaDataTemplateSelector, EukaryotaDataTemplateSelector).

Comment: @susieloo_ Why do you want each domain to have its own DataTemplateSelector? It's not clear to me what you gain in return for the added complexity.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I understand this approach doesn't really have any added functional value for me - it's more about organization/modularization, knowing that any large number of "domains and subdomains" will be added in this context and dont want a single DataTemplateSelector to include hundreds of templates.

Comment: @susieloo_ If it's more than three or four, I would find an entirely different way of looking them up, rather than hard-coding each one. For example, give them resource keys based on the C# class name or something. It's hard to be sure, since you haven't even given a clear answer whether there's a one-to-one relationship between DataTemplates and C# classes. But "hundreds" of templates is very, very unusual. Can you provide an example of two or three of these templates, and the C# classes they're meant to be used with? I think it's possible that we can **massively** simplify this thing.

Comment: I have decided to use a different approach based on all the feedback you have all given me. Just wanted to take the time to say thank you @EdPlunkett (+ Andy and Clemens, wasn't able to tag them) - I really appreciate you taking the time to give me your input and assistance. I'll close the question in a few hours to give you enough time to see this comment. :)

Comment: @susieloo_ Sounds good. Note that if I were implementing what you describe, I'd be writing maybe three C# classes and two or three DataTemplates, with no template selector. I hope you're not making extra work for yourself.